# Some Error about PrimeFaces in Maven Project (JSF)

Tags: primefaces

I created a Maven Project and created a .xhtml file. I want to use PrimeFaces, i used before and i have no problem. But now when i used, i get error like this;

"Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.org/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace."

I think, i did every necessary settings.  I added this in my pom.xml file;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>



<repositories>

    <!-- PrimeFaces Repostrory -->
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <!-- PrimeFaces Repostrory -->

</repositories>
```

And i added library in login.xhtml;

```
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

How can i fix this? I'm waiting for your help.

Comment: after PrimeFaces 4 you don't need to declare a repository, it's a part of the Maven Rep. On the other hand try to clean and compile using `mvn`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse you can try put the primefaces jar file into the JSF2.0 user library.
Source: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=71828&sid=8d595e7d7f045bd1a85268650c3c4cf2#p71828